# easy way to get annotation value of object member in Java

Tags: java, annotations

Given an annotated instance attribute in Java, how could you get the annotation value of an attribute? i.e. how would you implement getFraction() below if there are lots of BigDecimal attributes in the object?

It would be nice, if getFraction() would not need a String parameter "amount", the reference to the attribute would be sufficient and the code would survive refactoring the amount attribute name.

```
@Digits(integer=16, fraction=2)
private BigDecimal amount;

public void setAmount(double d)
{
    amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
    amount.setScale(Util.getFraction(amount));
}
```

Comment: There is no _reference to the attribute_. You could create a `Field` for each of your instance variables and use it to retrieve corresponding annotations. I don't see the point here though. It's hardcoded in your source code anyway. Just set it to 2.

Comment: I had hoped, that you can get at runtime the corresponding Field for an Object reference, actually I wanted the annotation for a reference, but it seems you cannot. So the given solutions are good for me.

Comment: Note that annotation.fraction() returns an int.

And you cannot setScale() on a given BigDecimal, they are immutable, setScale() returns a new BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the annotations of a field given it's value.

When you are calling your "Util" method, all you are passing it is the value of the field. It won't have enough information to access the annotation.

Here is a way you might do it...

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Digits(fraction = 2, integer = 16)
    private BigDecimal amount;


    private void setAmount(double d) {
        amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);

        amount.setScale(Util.getFraction(this, "amount"));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass().setAmount(12.3);
    }
}
```

Notice I'm passing the instance of the object that the field is in and the name of the field to my "Util" method.

It can now get the actual value like this...

```
public class Util {

    public static int getFraction(Object obj, String fieldName) {
        try {
            Digits annotation = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName).getAnnotation(Digits.class);
            return annotation.fraction();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            // BOOM!
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went awfully wrong...", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` to your annotation, otherwise it won't be available at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

Annotation value will be limited to the class itself and it doesn't come from the `Field` so it will be same for all the instance of the class.

Here's an example.

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TestAnnotation {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Digits {
        public int integer() default 0;
        public double fraction() default 0.0;
    }

    public static class TestClass {     
        @Digits(integer=16, fraction=2)
        private BigDecimal amount;
    }

    public static class Util {  
        public static double getFractionFromObject (Class<TestClass> klass) {
            double fraction = 0.0;
            try {
                Field amountField = klass.getDeclaredField("amount");

                Digits annotation = amountField.getAnnotation(Digits.class);
                fraction = annotation.fraction();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return fraction;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double fraction = Util.getFractionFromObject(TestClass.class);

        System.out.println("Fraction is : " + fraction);
    }
}
```